# How to resize image on window resize in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, image, responsive-design

I want to resize an image when I resize the window.

My window is `1600x1200`.
My image is `1000x500`.

I tried to use `background-size: cover`, it works but the image quality is very poor.

So is there an alternative to keep the image to 1000px max if the window is larger than 1000px **and** resize based on the screen if it is less than 1000px (such as `background-size: cover`) ?

Comment: Use "em" unit, to example width: 10em;

Comment: Is the background-image on your body?

Comment: @ChrisLaarman Nope, on a div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, with media query

```
@media(min-width:1000px){
.class{background-size: auto}
}
@media(max-width:999px){
.class{background-size: cover}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Detection of screen dimensions**

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height; 
var img = document.getElementById(image_id); 
img.height = img.height * width / img.width;
img.width = width;
```

**CSS:**

```
img{ width: 100% }
```

Comment: aren't we looking for a pure CSS solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Hy, try this:

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```